# Serializing Multiple Enum Values in WebApi

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, enums, json.net

If I have an Enum like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum EyeColor {
    All = 1,
    Brown = 2,
    Blue = 4,
    Hazel = 8,
    Green = 16
}
```

And then return a JSON result like this:

```
jsonBody.EyeColor = EyeColor.Brown | EyeColor.Blue;
```

I see the following in my jsonBody on the client:

```
"Brown, Blue"
```

However if I send the above string to WebAPI via an EyeColor property:

```
var eyeColor = "Brown, Blue"
var query = '?Index=1&EyeColor=` + eyeColor;
// send json GET request and use [FromUri] to extract
```

Serverside, I get:

```
dto.EyeColor: 0
```

Though if I do this:

```
var eyeColor = "All"
var query = '?Index=1&EyeColor=` + eyeColor;
// send json GET request and use [FromUri] to extract
```

I get

```
dto.EyeColor: All
```

So what I'm wondering is - in the event where I want to not only retrieve a string-serialized Enum from WebApi, but also send a string to represent multiple Enums that have been selected (and deserialized into multiple enums), what do I need to do?

My Global.asax:

```
        JsonSerializerSettings jSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
           GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = jSettings;

      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
      .Formatters
      .JsonFormatter
      .SerializerSettings
      .ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

```
"Brown,+Blue"
```

Is all that was needed.